# Timer object inconsistently accessible

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am starting a Python Timer in a Django view and I am using another Django view to cancel it. However, I find that I cannot access the Timer object consistently when I am trying to cancel it.

The code in my "views.py" looks like this:

```
import threading

myTimer = None

def f():
    pass

def startTimer(request):
    global myTimer

    myTimer = threading.Timer(10000, f)
    myTimer.start()
    pass

def stopTimer(request):
    if myTimer != None:
        myTimer.cancel()
    else:
        print("No timer found.")
    pass
```

When I try to cancel the timer, many times, I get the "No timer found." message. After some tries, seemingly in a random fashion, the Timer object is found and the cancellation succeeds. This phenomenon happens only when I run the code on the server. When the code runs on my local machine, this problem never happens.

Comment: What do you use as your server software? Is it configured to run as a single process or multiple processes?  I suspect you have multiple processes on your server, so the Timer object exists in one process, but doesn't exist in another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must never use global objects like this in a server environment. Your server almost certainly has multiple processes, each of which have their own local namespaces, so the timer won't be shared between them.

A second reason is that you will likely have multiple users for your site; all of them will have access to the same global variables in each process.

I'm not really sure what you're doing here, but one way of doing a per-user timer would be to use the [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/) to store the current time when the user hits start, and then calculate the difference from that time when they click end.